# Ulam's Spiral with Oppermann's Diagonals (quarter-squares)

Tags: graphs-and-networks, number-theory

First we craft a function to return the quadrant boundary based on [Oppermann's Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppermann%27s_conjecture)

```
a[n_] := (Mod[n, 2] + n^2 + 2 n)/4
```

Then we create a few lists

```
r = 10;
q = 1;
q1 = Table[a[q + 4 (n - 1)] <-> a[q + 4 (n)], {n, 1, r}];
q = 2;
q2 = Table[a[q + 4 (n - 1)] <-> a[q + 4 (n)], {n, 1, r}];
q = 3;
q3 = Table[a[q + 4 (n - 1)] <-> a[q + 4 (n)], {n, 1, r}];
q = 4;
q4 = Table[a[q + 4 (n - 1)] <-> a[q + 4 (n)], {n, 1, r}];
u = Flatten[Table[{(n - 1) <-> n}, {n, 2, a[4 + 4 r] + 1}]];
```

We produce the normal [Ulam's Spiral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSpiral.html)

```
Graph[u]
```

[image: Ulam's Spiral]

We don't get the spiral when we attempt to combine the diagonal lists by using this

```
Graph[Union[u, q1, q2, q3, q4]]
```

[image: Ulam Bad Spiral]

How can we overlay the diagonals onto the spiral?

Comment: Honestly, I'm quite surprised that `Graph[u]` produces a spiral!  None of the built-in layout methods give this specific layout.  It must be treating this graph as a special case.

Comment: I have linked from here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151902/ulams-spiral-oppermanns-diagonals-and-the-golden-ratio

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Starting with `Graph[u]` you can extract the coordinates of the vertices as follows

```
gr = Graph[u];
crds = AbsoluteOptions[gr, VertexCoordinates];
```

The graph including the diagonals can then be drawn according to

```
Graph[VertexList[gr], Union[u, q1, q2, q3, q4], crds]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: And I was silly enough to sit down and figure out a closed form for the vertex coordinate based on the index ... of course just extract them!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `GraphEmbedding` to get the vertex coordinates:

```
Graph[VertexList[g = Graph[u]], Union[u, q1, q2, q3, q4],
      VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g]]
```

[image]